# Еще по пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Такое сложное предложение из того же текста: "В деловых вопросах Драйзер не силен и всю жизнь пользуется самым примитивным набором стереотипных решений: не получается заработать — надо экономить, не получается сделать самому — надо нанять специалиста, нет денег оплатить его услуги — надо терпеть неудобства и копить деньги".
Правильно ли тут расставлены знаки препинания?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно. Предложение двухчастное: 1 часть до двоеточия, вторая - после. Вторая часть поясняет, раскрывает смысл первой (какими именно решениями, поэтому стоит двоеточие. Вторая часть представляет собой три пары бессоюзных сложных предложений, между парами - запятые. Внутри пары стоят тире, так как в первой части содержится условие (если не получается..., то надо...).